# How to change current time to user time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a Java GUI on a clock which asks the user to change the time from current time. I have the system time and the user time. What should be the code so that the user time gets displayed. The foolowing code i am using  :

```
        Date curDate = new Date();
        //changeTime i have got from the user
        double time=0;
        if(curDate.getTime()- changeTime.getTime() > 0){
            time = curDate.getTime() - changeTime.getTime();
            time = time/(1000);
        }
        else{
            time = changeTime.getTime()-curDate.getTime();
            time = time/(1000);
        }
        if(changeTime.getHours()==0 && changeTime.getMinutes()==0){
            time=0;
        }
        curDate.setHours(curDate.getHours()+(int)time/(3600));
        curDate.setMinutes(curDate.getMinutes()+((int)time/60)%60);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `new Date()` is "intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC)." What the user sees on the clock depends on the `TimeZone`, which can be specified in the `DateFormat` used  to render the date. The example below prints the same instant in GMT and a selection of time zones from New York to Berlin.

Addendum: I find it helpful to think of `Date` as a *model* and `DateFormat` as a *view* of that model.

```
03-Feb-2013 18:01:42 GMT GMT 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 13:01:42 EST America/New_York 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 14:01:42 AST America/Aruba 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 15:01:42 ART America/Buenos_Aires 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 16:01:42 BRST America/Sao_Paulo 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 17:01:42 AZOT Atlantic/Azores 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 18:01:42 GMT Europe/London 1359914502673
03-Feb-2013 19:01:42 CET Europe/Berlin 1359914502673
```

package date;

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14675418/230513 */
public class TestSDF {

    private static final String s = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zz";
    private static final DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(s);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        print("GMT", date);
        print("America/New_York", date);
        print("America/Aruba", date);
        print("America/Buenos_Aires", date);
        print("America/Sao_Paulo", date);
        print("Atlantic/Azores", date);
        print("Europe/London", date);
        print("Europe/Berlin", date);
    }

    private static void print(String tz, Date d) {
        f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));
        System.out.println(f.format(d)
            + " " + tz
            + " " + d.getTime());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one simple approach would be **get system time** and `add` `subtract` according to the user time.

for example system time is 2pm and user changes time to 4pm then just add 2 more hrs to system time and display it in your required field of user time

Comment: I have pasted the code, but i am not getting the correct result.

Comment: not getting correct result? what sort of wrong result you getting